# Matlab - publish file in PDF-format

Tags: matlab, publish

I have a question regarding Matlab's option to publish in PDF.  Say I have the following code:

```
%1D functions and plotting

%1. We calculate y given the following function: y(x) = 2x^2 +
%3x + 1, for x = 10.
x = 10;
y = 2*x.^2 + 3*x + 1

%2. We calculate y given the following function: y(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, with a
%=2, b=3, c=0 and x = 100.
a=2;
b=3;
c=0;
x=100;
y = a*x.^2 + b*x + c

. . . more code follows here
```

When I choose to publish this as PDF the answers to problems 1 and 2 (where I calculate two different values for the variable 'y') do not appear at the line where I calculate the value (where I write `y = 2*x.^2 + 3*x + 1` for instance).  Instead, the values of the 'y' variables appear at the end of the document where it says 'y = 231' and 'y = 20300'.  Is there any way I can get this to be included right after I define the variable without separating the document into cells?  Or is this a default thing that I can not do anything about?  I would really appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach (indipendent of the output format) is to **restart the paragraph** with line break and `%%`:

```
%% 1. We calculate y given the following function: y(x) = 2x^2 +
% 3x + 1, for x = 10.
x = 10;
y = 2*x.^2 + 3*x + 1

%% 2. We calculate y given the following function: y(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, with a
% =2, b=3, c=0 and x = 100.
a=2;
b=3;
c=0;
x=100;
y = a*x.^2 + b*x + c
```

Comment: OK. Thanks!  Appreciate your input!